# Unable to collapse empty slot DFP

Tags: google, google-adsense, google-dfp

I tried to collapse a slot and its not working .. apparently dfp mark it as not empty .

```
googletag.cmd.push(function() {
    googletag.defineSlot('/21323213123/slot', [[1, 1]], 'div-gpt-ad-31331133133-0').setTargeting('site', [ 'foot' ]).setTargeting('category', [ 'home' ]).setTargeting('page', [ '' ]).setTargeting('tag_championnat', [ '' ]).setTargeting('tag_equipe', [ '' ]).setTargeting('page_type', [ 'wp' ]).addService(googletag.pubads()); 
    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest();
    googletag.pubads().collapseEmptyDivs();
    googletag.enableServices();
});
```

The iframe generated has some  tag with javascript in it

Answer (score 1):

Collapsing empty slots does not mean not creating them.
DFP will create the slot and then hide it.
Therefore there's no reason to worry about the iframe being generated unless it shows up an empty space.

Also, make sure you add the script in the `<head>` portion of your page, or it won't work properly.

[Collapsing empty div elements](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/3072674?hl=en)